# Flyway Unable to instantiate jdbc driver

Tags: database, spring, flyway

Just starting out with Flyway and Spring 3.0. So far, all I did was add the Flyway dependency and plugin to my pom.xml. Next, I tried running `mvn flyway:status` in the command line. However, it complains that it is unable to instantiate the jdbc driver (I'm using postgres).

Does anybody know what might be causing this? I'm using Springsource Tool Suite to develop my app. The postgres driver is located under WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the Maven plugin to work you must:

Add this dependency to your project (or just the plugin):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

and configure the plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:postgresql://...</url>
        <user>...</user>
        <password>...</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to provide the Postgresql jdbc drivers as a maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-902.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```